# mySQL - Find Context of a big List of Keywords in one field

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb, sql-like, keyword

Im in dispair with this one.

I have a field in my Maria MySql DB that contains data like this:

```
Dummydata Dummydata

Dummydata Dummydata 15

Dummydata 124578 KEYWORD
```

It can also looke like this in die last line:

```
Dummydata 124578KEYWORD
```

or

```
Dummydata 124578-KEYWORD
```

etc

Now I have a list of about 3000 keywords, that need to be excludes in my results, this is basicly the only criteria I have.

I have try like this

```
AND NOT (FIELD LIKE '%KEYWORD1%' OR FIELD  LIKE '%KEYWORD2%')
```

Here it just retuns everything, like it has been ignored

and

```
AND NOT (FIELD IN ('%KEYWORD1%','%KEYWORD2%')')
```

Here it looke like that it just searches in the first paragraph

It doesnt seem to work :(

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For only a few keywords,  you could use `NOT REGEXP` / `NOT RLIKE`

```
AND FIELD NOT RLIKE '[0-9]+[ -]?(keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)'
```

You could also create a table with the keywords. Then use a `NOT EXISTS` with an `RLIKE`

```
AND NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM wordstoavoid w
   WHERE t.FIELD RLIKE CONCAT('[0-9]+[ -]?', w.word)
);
```

A test can be found [here](http://rextester.com/EOX74118)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help. unfortunatly the first two dont work. Ill try the last one tomorrow

Comment: I tryd it, but it doesnt seem to work, it returns a result where the keywords are excluded, but also much more excluded, so i get like 150 rows, but it should be like 1000

Comment: @Intercept0r This time the regex used will check for digits and optional space/dash before the keyword. That could yield different results.

Comment: The method with the table worked perfectly! Thank u so much!

Comment: With MariaDB 10.2, see `\b`.  For MySQL, see `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`.  These define word boundaries.